# Excel sumif with criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a last_name, first_name, salary, and total_salary columns.  The sales person appears multiple times throughout the spread sheet.  What I would like to do is write a function that will sum up the salary column in the total_salary column only where the sales person appears.

Example output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table? Its very powerful and made just for situations like this. http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/

Comment: All great answers.  Thank you everyone for your quick responses.

Comment: @Tone you're welcome, and do not neglect that pivot table advice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming your data is in columns `A:C` starting row 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1=A:A),--(B1=B:B),C:C)
```

Autofit down the list as required.

Comment: @Brad this will produce exactly what OP wants - according to added samples.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `SumIfs` function.

Suppose your data starts in cell A1

You Would have:

```
A        B       C       D
Brian    Adam    3000    =SUMIFS($C$1:$C$8,$A$1:$A$8,A1,$B$1:$B$8,B1)
```

And then just drag down column D

Obviously change the `$8` part of the function to the correct number of rows for the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `fname`, `lname` and `sal` columns named ranges

use this formula where ever you want.

```
=SUMIFS(Sal,Fname,"Brian",Lname,"Adam")
```

or

```
=SUMIFS(Sal,Fname,"A2",Lname,"B2")
```

You can replace`"Brian"` and `"Adam"` with range references too.

I case you are not familiar: Making a named range

[image]

editing a named range

[image]