# How to Concatenate, Increment and create new lines from concatenated date?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working in advertising and to generate complex campaigns we use a "Bulk Tool", in which we require to write the date manually and makes us lose a lot of precious time.

Here is what I am trying to do in Excel:

A form with this data:

```
PO Number: B2
Format: B3
Campaign Name: B4
Target Names:
Amount of Copys: B10 (Where B10 is a value between 1 and 10 for example)
Amount of Visuals: B11 (Where B11 is a value between 1 and 10 for example)
```

I believe the first step to automatize this procedure is to start by concatenating the data, which is done with:

```
=concatenate(B1,"_",B2,"_",B3,"_","T"B10,B11)
```

which should produce something like this:

```
165_ILF_TEST_T4_5
```

My real issue is that I actually have 4 copys and 5 visuals, which means that what I would like to be able to create automatically is this:

```
165_ILF_TEST_T1_1
165_ILF_TEST_T1_2
165_ILF_TEST_T1_3
165_ILF_TEST_T1_4
165_ILF_TEST_T1_5
165_ILF_TEST_T2_1
165_ILF_TEST_T2_2
165_ILF_TEST_T2_3
165_ILF_TEST_T2_4
165_ILF_TEST_T2_5
```

Any idea if this would require using loops within excel? I have strictly no idea how to perform it, although there's been some intensive thinking about this.

Thank you very much for your help,

Carlos

Answer (score 1):

Place this formula in cell A1 (or any other cell in row 1) and copy it down till row 100:

```
=IF(ROW()>$B$4*$B$5,
   "",
   $B$1&"_"&
   $B$2&"_"&
   $B$3&"_T"&
   INT((ROW()-1)/$B$5)+1&
   "_"&MOD(ROW()-1,$B$5)+1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Still no way I'll make the 3k before you gain another 6pt only! ;-)

Comment: That was a pure luck Peter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011338/excel-sumif-with-criteria/15011603#15011603 - gave me extra 55 points))) I simply was the first in the right place)

Comment: I know, though we all got those at some stage! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012497/generating-random-1-and-1-values-in-excel/15012520#15012520) Still, pretty cool effort reaching the 3K that quickly! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Shouldn't I replace the , with ; ?

Comment: this depends on your regional settings! if you normally separate arguments in a formula with `;` then yes!

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for disturbing again, but for some reason, it doesn't fully work. Basically when I put in 4 copys and 6 visuals, the formula should generate 6 T1 lines and 6 T2 lines, 6 T3 lines and 6 T4 lines (with a 1,2,3,4,5,6) at the end of it, but it stops itself after having generated T1 (6 visuals), T2 (6 visuals), T3 (only 4 visuals?), what is happening with T4 and the visuals?

Comment: do you start in row 1? it should stop after row 24 (that's what the first condition in the formula is there for)